# Accessing Boolean values by parsing JSON file using boost property tree

Tags: c++, json, c++11, boost-propertytree, boost-iterators

Below are the steps I followed to fetch values from a JSON file:

```json
{
  "Bases":[
    {
      "mnemonic":"ADIS.LA.01",
      "relay":true
    },
    {
      "mnemonic":"ALEX.LA.01",
      "relay":true
    }
  ]
}
```

I am failing to fetch the boolean values.

In the code below, I am:

1. Opening the JSON file
2. Setting the root element and start traversing the childtree under this root element (Bases)
3. Fetching the values of each tag and saving them to appropriate variable types.

Code:

```
ReadJsonFile()
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    const boost::property_tree::ptree& propTree
    boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt);
    const std::string rootElement = "Bases"; 
    boost::property_tree::ptree childTree;
    bool m_relay;
    try
    {
        /** get_child - Get the child at the given path, or throw @c ptree_bad_path. */
        childTree = propTree.get_child(rootElement);
    }
    catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path& ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

    BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, propTree.get_child(rootElement)){
       string vID;
       for (ptree::const_iterator subTreeIt = v.second.begin(); subTreeIt != v.second.end(); ++subTreeIt) {
          if (subTreeIt->first == "mnemonic")
          {
             // Get the value string and trim the extra spaces, if any
             vID = boost::algorithm::trim_copy( subTreeIt->second.data() );
          }
          if (subTreeIt->first == "relay")
          {
            m_relay = boost::algorithm::trim_copy(subTreeIt->second.data());
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Error:

> error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’ to ‘bool’ in assignment

Apparently the boolean value `"relay":true` is treated as a string instead of a `bool`.

If I change

```
bool m_relay;
```

to

```
std::string m_relay;
```

The code works fine, but the `bool` type is failing to compile.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597048/boost-property-tree-iterators-how-to-handle-them

Comment: I looked into that , it does'nt provide info about fetching boolen value using ptree::const_iterator  and thus i asked the question

Comment: @LearningCpp: actually, it does provide details of how to fetch different data types, if you read it more carefully. Try using `m_relay = subTreeIt->second.get_value<bool>();` instead of `m_relay = boost::algorithm::trim_copy(subTreeIt->second.data());`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
m_relay = subTreeIt->second.get_value<bool>();
```

Instead of this:

```
m_relay = boost::algorithm::trim_copy(subTreeIt->second.data());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it manually:

`boost::lexical_cast<bool>(subTreeIt->second.data());`

But it doesn't seem like a preferred way. I urge you to read 
[Docs: How to Access Data in a Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/accessing.html).

However, I don't see another way using an iterator. So I guess you are fine, given that you already have it. The preferred ways seem to hinge on the path, which you do not use.

For what it's worth... You probably should use `find` instead of iterating manually, or refactor your code for some version of `get`. It seems like a better design.

Comment: How about this ? This works too ;
   if (boost::iequals ( subTreeIt->second.data() , "false"))
               m_relay = false;

Comment: Yea, but why if? What if user puts in `flase` or `0`?

Comment: it has to fail , it should fail if it's anything other than true or false

Comment: And you don't handle it... lexical_cast does.

Comment: Does the code fail if its other than true or false?

Comment: Error while traversing : exception: bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target.

Comment: with input as true and false the code is failing with  exception: bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target.